# Random API Output?

Tags: javascript, api, response

```
async:true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            parseArray(response._embedded.events)
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        }
    });
} 
);

function parseArray(response){
    for( let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        createElement("<h2>", response[i].name);
        console.log(response[i]);
    }
}

function createElement(type, string){
    var artistHolder = $("<div>");
    var artist = $(""+type);

    $(artist).text(string);
    artistHolder.append(artist);
    //append div to container
    $("#container").append(artistHolder);

}
```

So I am trying to randomize the response I'm appending to my container, but all of my attempts to use `Math.floor(Math.random())` have come up empty... I have tried working with the API's endpoints and that hasn't helped me either. I am new to all of this... The code above simply appends the same response over and over again. Thanks for your help if any in advance.

Comment: Show us the code you couldn't get to work correctly.  It's hard to help you with code we can't see.  the code in the question doesn't show us how you were trying to randomize.

Comment: To what end?  Say you receive [1,2,3] from the ajax response, are you looking to display [3,1,2] (ie, shuffle the array) or display a random element or a random number of elements?  Can you give us an example of your ajax data and and example of what you mean by "randomize it"?

Answer (score 2):

Math.random() returns a value in range [0..1[ - when you floor it, you will always get 0
To get a number in range 0..1000 you have to multiply it, before you execute floor.

use e.g.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have an AXIOS call where I use this logic:  document.getElementById('container3').innerHTML = result.data.businesses[Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1)].name; 20 is the number of hits I am getting back from my API, and it totally works there... My issue is I don't know where to insert the random math methods into the above AJAX call... I have tried attaching it numerous places... response? response._embedded.events? I have tried a bunch of variations. Is the for loop blocking the execution? Thanks again!